# Android Studio Moto 360 Debugging

Tags: debugging, android-studio, bluetooth, adb, moto-360

I have followed the steps posted to debug over bluetooth here http://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/bt-debugging.html
but I do not know where to run the commands for adb, I am using mac and android studio version 1.5.1 with adb integration enabled.

No matter what I do, I can't seem to get my moto 360 to connect to the host. Any help would be appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can run adb command in a `terminal` of the system or `terminal tab` inside the Android Studio